# Error while RTSP streaming URL in Android using VideoView

Tags: android

I am trying to play RTSP Streaming URL in Android using VideoView. Please find the code snippet below,

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("rtsp://hostname:port/path");        
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

I am receiving the first frame and video gets stopped.

Further i have analyzed the adb logs.
I am receiving `onPreparedListener` and `onInfoListener`(twice). 
For First `onInfoListener`, i am receiving second parameter as `MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START`
For Second `onInfoListener`, i am receiving second parameter as `MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END`

If anybody have faced this issue or have any suggestion , please.

Note: Instead of android platform, i have run vlc player in LINUX using same RTSP url. It works fine.

Comment: What's your rtsp link? it maybe depended on RTSP server!

Comment: RTSP url and RTSP server is fine. I have verified with vlc player installed in linux. I am running rtsp server in linux platform. I am wondering how its not working in android platform.